# Java Webservice unmarshal issue

Tags: java, web-services

I am sending a request to webservice and am receiving correct response from web service in xml format with the correct value populated in the response element tags. Now I tried to unmarshal but the response object is being populated with null instead of the value I see in XML response.

Here is my code:

```
org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext _returnMessageContext = 
    _operationClient.getMessageContext(
        org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDLConstants.MESSAGE_LABEL_IN_VALUE);
org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPEnvelope _returnEnv = _returnMessageContext.getEnvelope();


java.lang.Object object = fromOM(
    _returnEnv.getBody().getFirstElement(),
    com.siebel.asi.QueryByExample1Output.class,
    getEnvelopeNamespaces(_returnEnv));
```

and following method :

```
try {
    javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext context = wsContext;
    javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

    return unmarshaller.unmarshal(
        param.getXMLStreamReaderWithoutCaching(),
        type).getValue();
} catch (javax.xml.bind.JAXBException bex) {
```

The response object is becoming null even though I can see output response in XML format.
This is how I am setting up wscontext :

```
private static final javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext wsContext;
        static {
            javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext jc;
            jc = null;
            try {
                jc = javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(
            com.siebel.asi.QueryByExample1Input.class,
                        com.siebel.asi.QueryByExample1Output.class,
                        com.siebel.asi.QueryById1Input.class,
                        com.siebel.asi.QueryById1Output.class
                );
            }
            catch ( javax.xml.bind.JAXBException ex ) {
                System.err.println("Unable to create JAXBContext: " + ex.getMessage());
                ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
                Runtime.getRuntime().exit(-1);
            }
            finally {
                wsContext = jc;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727949/webservice-unmarshalling-issue). If you want help, you're going to have to post more useful information. Posting repeatedly will not get you an answer.

Comment: I'm assuming that the second block is the `fromOM` method?  The signature of that method would help, also how you're setting up the `wsContext` in the lower block.

Comment: I have added code to the above questions please see and let me know and yes you are correct that is fromOM methods